# how do you convert javascript object with arrays in to array of objects with corresponding name and value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

Fellow programmer here, for some reason I have spent two days but I cannot do this properly so help me out.
I have an object with arrays for each key like this:

```js
var arraysObject = {
    "North American": [
        "CONUS",
        "NAMER",
        "CONUS/AK",
        "US-NC",
        "US-NE",
        "US-NW",
        "US-SC",
        "US-SE"
    ],
    "Oconus": [
        "ALASKA",
        "GUAM",
        "HAWAII",
        "POLAR",
        "US-SAMOA"
    ],
 }
```

I have a list of areas that have been selected, like the following

```js
var listOfAreas = ["CONUS", "GUAM","US-SAMOA"]
```

I want to create the following object:

```js
var result = [{
        "North American":"CONUS",
        "Oconus": "GUAM"
        },
        {
        "North American": "",
        "Oconus":"US-SAMOA"
        }]
```

Notice how it created a new object only when that last one's key is full and fills the object if possible. in my implementation it creates an object for each individual string and assigns it to the key using then pushes it using .map
This doesn't work. I want it to fill each object accordingly and create an new object only when it is necessary. Appreciate your help.
Best,
A dummy.

Comment: What happens with two "North American" results like `[CONUS, NAMER]`? Because it seems the "unique" values should be come the keys, not the other way around.

Comment: I'm not able to understand the data structure you are trying to create. are you able to clarify?

Comment: the data structure is an array of objects, basically an inverse of the first object with only the strings in the selected array. This is used to create a table with bootstrap and needs to be in that format.

Comment: @RandyCasburn CONUS was the only selected string in the list of arrays that was in the North America array

Comment: @TadewosBellete - yes, I understand what you provided as an example. My question has to do with different input arrays that may contain two elements from North America. Can that ever happen in your app?

Comment: yes then the second object would have the North American field filled. The key with most inputs dictates how many objects should be in the array. Does that make sense?

Comment: I suppose something like this still confuses me:  '["CONUS", "NAMER", "ALASKA","GUAM","US-NE"] - but hey, doesn't matter. Thanks for taking time to try to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object for keeping track of the indices for the keys and take a helper object for the reverted value/key relation.

```js
const
    arraysObject = { "North American": ["CONUS", "NAMER", "CONUS/AK", "US-NC", "US-NE", "US-NW", "US-SC", "US-SE"], "Oconus": ["ALASKA", "GUAM", "HAWAII", "POLAR", "US-SAMOA"] },
    keys = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(arraysObject).flatMap(([k, a]) => a.map(v => [v, k]))),
    EMPTY = Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(arraysObject).map(k => [k, ''])),
    listOfAreas = ["CONUS", "GUAM","US-SAMOA"],
    indices = {},
    result = [];

listOfAreas.forEach(value => {
    const key = keys[value];
    indices[key] ??= 0;
    (result[indices[key]++] ??= { ...EMPTY })[key] = value;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: But hold on, it is giving me duplicate values during implementation.

Comment: where do you get duplicates? the values should be unique.

Comment: oh debugging showed that the slected list has duplicates for some reason. .map giving duplicates some how. not your code lol

Comment: can you explain how the lines in the ForEach works? I am not sure I get how it works.

Comment: it gets the `key` from the `keys` object, assigns zero to the indices object with this key or keeps the value if not `null` or undefined` ([logical nullish assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment), this is used later with a spreading of an object with only emtpty strings as values).

Comment: in the last line the assignment takes place by using the index from `indices` (where the index is incremented), a check is made for `null` or `undefined`, the object is in this case assigned and finally the value goes to its right place with index and key.